# GitHubPages - Jekyll Template generated correctly from README.md failed

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I've the following problem...
I created a [GitHub-Page](https://0x1c1b.github.io/JContacts/) for my project, because I'm not a webpage developer and don't have any special skills in HTML or CSS, I generated this page by a [template](https://github.com/pages-themes/modernist) you can choose from your repository settings...

Now I have the problem that the Jekyll page generated from template combined with my *README.md* doesn't show the preview image. In my *README.md* file I specified the image with this tag:

```
| ![Preview Image](https://github.com/0x1C1B/JContacts/blob/master/doc/img/preview.png) | 
|:--:| 
| *Preview image of application* |
```

But Jekyll displays only the subscription of the image, you can see it [here](https://0x1c1b.github.io/JContacts/).
Is it possible to solve this bug or is it a template depended problem?

**EDIT:** This is the generated HTML code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center"><img src="https://github.com/0x1C1B/JContacts/blob/master/doc/img/preview.png" alt="Preview Image" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center"><em>Preview image of application</em></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an absolute-url to an image in your GitHub repository, use the link to "raw" image instead.
In other words, use the following URL instead:

**`https://github.com/0x1C1B/JContacts/raw/master/doc/img/preview.png`**